# loopback ACL for user model

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using loopback to create a simple API for a SPA website. I want to keep my permissions as simple as possible, so I ended up with a following ACL model

- all permissions are denied by default
- some methods in several models are allowed for everyone
- all methods are allowed for any authorized user

this will obviously work if I will create several users and no one will be able to create or modify users anymore. As I can't explicitly change permissions for built-in `User` model, I created an `admin` model, that extends `User`. Then I set `public` property of `User` model to false.  I set the following ACL rules

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "login"
},
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$authenticated",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

as I see it, it should deny any unathorized user access to any methods other than `login`.

Unfortunately that is not how it works, anyone still can POST to /users and create new users. My guess is that ACL rules do not apply to inherited model, so rules for `User` are applied here. So I'm back to square one, I can't either change `User` permissions directly or override them.

What are my options here? Is there no way to prevent creating new users?

Answer (score 3):

As it turned out, the rule specifics matter more than inheritance level. In this case, `User` model defines a rule specifically for `create` property. This rule takes precendence over a more general deny every property, even though the deny rule was defined in the extended `admin` model. So I had to take all allowed rules from `User` model and deny them explicitly in `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue few days ago and i found this solution. loopback default **POST /Users** rule is everyone can insert user. So your admin model inherited from User model thus rules are inherited too. We will have to override create permission in your admin model.
[Loopback User model Default permission for POST](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L31)

Just put below object in acl in **common/models/admin.json**

```
...
 acl : [{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY",
  "property": "create"
},{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$authenticated",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "create"
}]
...
```

Thus you first **DENY** access to **$everyone** by overriding default rule and set Rule for only  **$authenticated** which will be able to post.
You can set rule as per your requirements.